# Drag and Drop event.dataTransfer.files is empty

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to collect data every time image is dropped inside the div. My server receives empty data not even a single thing. All I need is image name "green-glass-arrow.png" to display. You can see it inside "console"
What am I doing wrong? please help!
[You can see example here](http://codepen.io/solosurge/pen/YqZVxe)

JavaScript

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
console.log(event.dataTransfer.files);
}
```

**Final result. Transferring image data on drag and drop to MySql using JavaScrip AJAX to PHP**

Edited Code

```
<script>

function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var ele = document.getElementById(data);    
    console.log(document.getElementById(data).name); 
    ajax_post(ele);
}

// ----AJAX Post to PHP----->
function ajax_post(ele){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "insert.php";
    var imgName = ele.name;
    var imgId = ele.id;

    var vars = "imgName="+imgName+"&imgId="+imgId;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
}    

</script>
```

PHP Code "insert.php"

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','your_password');

    if(!$con) {
        echo 'Not Connected To Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, 'your_table')) {
        echo 'Database Not Selected';
    }

    $imgName = $_POST['imgName'];
    $imgId = $_POST['imgId'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO schema_name (name,id) 
    VALUES ('$imgName','$imgId')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        echo 'Not Inserted';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Inserted';
    }
?>
```

Comment: In the example, I changed html to <img src="http://animations.fg-a.com/arrows/green-glass-arrow.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="credit5" class="player" name="green-glass-arrow.png" > and in Js I changed to console.log(document.getElementById(data).name); to get image name.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you send me an example, I think it might work...

Comment: http://codepen.io/TShah/pen/aNYMaX

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need, why don't you post it as an answer so I can give you a credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

codepen.io/TShah/pen/aNYMaX

```
        <script>

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        var ele = document.getElementById(data);    
        console.log(document.getElementById(data).name); 
        ajax_post(ele);
    }

    // ----AJAX Post to PHP----->
    function ajax_post(ele){
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
        var url = "insert.php";
        var imgName = ele.name;
        var imgId = ele.id;

        var vars = "imgName="+imgName+"&imgId="+imgId;

        hr.open("POST", url, true);
        // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                        var return_data = hr.responseText;
                            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
                }
        }
        // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
        hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";
    }    

    </script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you help me with posting AJAX to PHP. Inserting the same data. I updated JS inside codepen. Much appreciated...

Comment: Just had a chance to look at the code you sent me. Its so clear now what I was missing and gives perfect results in MySql. Thank you for your time!!!